# R6RS Library body: definition after expression

Tags: scheme, racket, r6rs

Consider the following code:

```lisp
#!r6rs
(library
 (test)
 (export)
 (import (rnrs))

 (define a 5)
 (begin
   (define b 4)
   (+ 3 b))
 'cont
 (define c 5)
 'done)
```

From the [R6RS Report 7.1](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-10.html):

> A <library body> is like a <body> (see section 11.3) except that a <library body>s need not include any expressions. It must have the following form:
>
> `<definition> ... <expression> ...`

I thought it would emit error because definition of `c` is after expression `'cont`, but this program is accepted cleanly.

After Then, I thought `a` and `c` could be exported. But, not `c` but `b` can be exported. (`a` can be exported as I thought.)

I think there are something I didn't realize about R6RS library rules. What is the point I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

p.s) I'm using Racket v5.3.3

Comment: You are correct. The definition of `c` should be an error. This is the case with IronScheme and Chez Petite. I can only assume a Racket bug or relaxed semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the R6RS 2007 specification:

```
A library definition must have the following form:

(library <library name>
  (export <export spec> ...)

  (import <import spec> ...)

  <library body>)


...

 The <library body> is the library body, consisting of a sequence of definitions 
 followed by a sequence of expressions. The definitions may be both for local 
 (unexported) and exported bindings, and the expressions are initialization 
 expressions to be evaluated for their effects.
```

Thus, for your example code, an error should have been raised.

Comment: At first time, I thought the example code should emit some errors. However, in Racket 5.3.3, it accepted. So, (considering leppie's answer) I concluded that it is Racket's "habit".

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry, this is not the right answer. It is how the program toplevel works, not library toplevel.** Leaving it here for reference.

In the program toplevel things work a bit different from normal (normal being the way you interpreted it).

The code will be rewritten by the compiler to look something like:

```
(define a 5)
(define b 4)
(define dummy1 (+ 3 b))
(define dummy2 'cont)
(define c 5)
'done
```

**Notes:**

- `begin` splices in the toplevel
- For any non-definition, the expression is assigned to a 'dummy' variable
- The toplevel eventually ends up looking like a `letrec*` and the same rules apply

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I started worrying it might be very hard to make portable R6RS code.

Comment: @Venusaur: Portable code is quite easy with R6RS. The only non-portable bit I am aware of is differences in phase handling during macro expansion.